# Linking to Google+ profile gives error on iOS Safari

Tags: html, ios, mobile-safari, google-plus

I am linking to my Google+ profile in HTML:

```
<a href="https://plus.google.com/114612681040321002952/posts"></a>
```

And on iPhone/Safari it is giving the following error:

"Cannot Open Page. Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid." (screenshot below)

However, the page is visible underneath the error message. And once the message is dismissed, the site can be navigated fine. Seems more like an issue with Google+ since my code is so basic.

[image]?

Comment: It is trying to open Google+ app. If you don't want it to open app in the first place just change link to -> https://plus.google.com/app/basic/114612681040321002952/posts?source=appredir

Comment: Keep in mind that anyone not on a mobile device that follows that link will now get a crappy mobile site.

Comment: Indeed. I realized that pretty quick after implementing it. So I left the original link in there, and then put in a jQuery rule to change the href on mobile devices.